# I'm trying to read excel sheets and writing to text boxes in VB.Net. But it is not working when number of columns is less than 12

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

```
Dim L As Long
    L = w.Worksheets.Count

    Dim F As Integer = 1
    For F = 1 To L
        ' Get sheet.
        Dim sheet As Worksheet = w.Sheets(F)

        ' Get range.
        Dim r As Range = sheet.UsedRange

        ' Load all cells into 2d array.
        Dim array(,) As Object = r.Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault)

        ' Scan the cells.
        If array IsNot Nothing Then
            Console.WriteLine("Length: {0}", array.Length)

            ' Get bounds of the array.
            Dim bound0 As Integer = array.GetUpperBound(0)
            Dim bound1 As Integer = array.GetUpperBound(1)
            Dim row As Integer = bound0
            Dim clmn As Integer = bound1
            Dim table As New System.Data.DataTable
            For col As Integer = 1 To bound1
                table.Columns.Add()
            Next
            ' Loop over all elements.
            For j As Integer = 1 To bound0

                Dim dr As DataRow = table.NewRow()

                For x As Integer = 1 To bound1

                    Dim s1 As String = array(j, x)
                    dr(x - 1) = array(j, x)
                    'Console.Write(s1)
                    'Console.Write(” “c)
                Next
                'Console.WriteLine()
                table.Rows.Add(dr)

            Next

            ' tb1.Text = table.Rows(0)(0)

            'Me.Controls("tb" & CStr(1)).Text = table.Rows(0)(0)
            Dim Form1 As New Form1

            Form1.A2T2.Text = table.Rows(2)(2)
            '    Form1.Controls("A" & CStr(1) & "T" & CStr(1)).Text = table.Rows(1)(1)


            Dim tbox() As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox = {Form1.T1, Form1.T2, Form1.T3, Form1.T4, Form1.T5, Form1.T6, Form1.T7, Form1.T8, Form1.T9, Form1.T10, Form1.T11, Form1.T12, Form1.T13, Form1.T14,
                                                          Form1.A1T1, Form1.A1T2, Form1.A1T3, Form1.A1T4, Form1.A1T5, Form1.A1T6, Form1.A1T7, Form1.A1T8, Form1.A1T9, Form1.A1T10, Form1.A1T11, Form1.A1T12, Form1.A1T13, Form1.A1T14,
                                                          Form1.A2T1, Form1.A2T2, Form1.A2T3, Form1.A2T4, Form1.A2T5, Form1.A2T6, Form1.A2T7, Form1.A2T8, Form1.A2T9, Form1.A2T10, Form1.A2T11, Form1.A2T12, Form1.A2T13, Form1.A2T14,
                                                          Form1.A3T1, Form1.A3T2, Form1.A3T3, Form1.A3T4, Form1.A3T5, Form1.A3T6, Form1.A3T7, Form1.A3T8, Form1.A3T9, Form1.A3T10, Form1.A3T11, Form1.A3T12, Form1.A3T13, Form1.A3T14,
                                                          Form1.A4T1, Form1.A4T2, Form1.A4T3, Form1.A4T4, Form1.A4T5, Form1.A4T6, Form1.A4T7, Form1.A4T8, Form1.A4T9, Form1.A4T10, Form1.A4T11, Form1.A4T12, Form1.A4T13, Form1.A4T14,
                                                          Form1.A5T1, Form1.A5T2, Form1.A5T3, Form1.A5T4, Form1.A5T5, Form1.A5T6, Form1.A5T7, Form1.A5T8, Form1.A5T9, Form1.A5T10, Form1.A5T11, Form1.A5T12, Form1.A5T13, Form1.A5T14,
                                                           Form1.A6T1, Form1.A6T2, Form1.A6T3, Form1.A6T4, Form1.A6T5, Form1.A6T6, Form1.A6T7, Form1.A6T8, Form1.A6T9, Form1.A6T10, Form1.A6T11, Form1.A6T12, Form1.A6T13, Form1.A6T14,
                                                           Form1.A7T1, Form1.A7T2, Form1.A7T3, Form1.A7T4, Form1.A7T5, Form1.A7T6, Form1.A7T7, Form1.A7T8, Form1.A7T9, Form1.A7T10, Form1.A7T11, Form1.A7T12, Form1.A7T13, Form1.A7T14,
                                                           Form1.A8T1, Form1.A8T2, Form1.A8T3, Form1.A8T4, Form1.A8T5, Form1.A8T6, Form1.A8T7, Form1.A8T8, Form1.A8T9, Form1.A8T10, Form1.A8T11, Form1.A8T12, Form1.A8T13, Form1.A8T14,
                                                         Form1.A9T1, Form1.A9T2, Form1.A9T3, Form1.A9T4, Form1.A9T5, Form1.A9T6, Form1.A9T7, Form1.A9T8, Form1.A9T9, Form1.A9T10, Form1.A9T11, Form1.A9T12, Form1.A9T13, Form1.A9T14,
                                                         Form1.A10T1, Form1.A10T2, Form1.A10T3, Form1.A10T4, Form1.A10T5, Form1.A10T6, Form1.A10T7, Form1.A10T8, Form1.A10T9, Form1.A10T10, Form1.A10T11, Form1.A10T12, Form1.A10T13, Form1.A10T14}

            Dim k As Integer = 0
            For a = 2 To row -1

                For b = 1 To clmn -1

                    tbox(k).Text = table.Rows(a)(b)
                    '  Form1.A1T1.Text = table.Rows(1)(2)

                    If (b = clmn - 1) Then
                        k = k + 1 + (13 - b)
                    End If
                    k = k + 1
                Next
            Next
            Form1.Fm.Text = table.Rows(0)(0)
            Rw = row - 3
            Clm = clmn - 2
            Form1.Rw = Rw
            Form1.Clm = Clm
            Form1.Show()
        End If


    Next
```

If my excel sheet contains less than 12 columns then it is showing error that "Null value cant be assigned to string". It works fine when number of columns are more than 12. Help me figure out this problem

Comment: Try to remove empty columns in excel sheet means select all empty columns and delete them, may be there some empty columns which are treated as null. May it help..

Comment: not too sure what your program does but guessing it is connected with this line `k = k + 1 + (13 - b)`

Comment: wow that work's right now..... I've deleted empty columns then it's working fine....Is there any other option to make it right without deleting columns but only values... thanku... @SiddiqueMahsud

Comment: please see link [**DeleteBlankRows/DeleteBlankColumns**](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsnet/Delete+Blank+Rows+and+Columns+in+a+Worksheet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Delete blank rows**

C#

```
Worksheet sheet = sheets[0];   
sheet.Cells.DeleteBlankRows();
```

VB

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet = sheets(0)
sheet.Cells.DeleteBlankRows()
```

**Delete blank Columns**

C#

```
Worksheet sheet = sheets[0];
sheet.Cells.DeleteBlankColumns();
```

VB

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet = sheets(0)
sheet.Cells.DeleteBlankColumns()
```

For more detail please see link [**DeleteBlankRows/DeleteBlankColumns**](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsnet/Delete+Blank+Rows+and+Columns+in+a+Worksheet)